# Cant load jdbc driver from Netbeans 12 JavaFX maven project

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc, netbeans

Hello i try to use JDBC Driver in a new javaFX maven project created with Netbeans 12 but each time i try to use jdbc driver i have java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver

I tried to add other jar dependencies and it works. Only jdbc drivers doesnt work. (Tried with microsoft sql server too same problem)

I have added dependency in maven. It works when i create a normal java maven project.. Thanks

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>module-info.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.mavenproject4.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>openjfx</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>[11,)</jdk>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
                    <version>11</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt400-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>10.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Main

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject4;

import com.ibm.as400.access.AS400;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        String javaVersion = SystemInfo.javaVersion();
        String javafxVersion = SystemInfo.javafxVersion();

        Label label = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(label), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
            Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver").newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        launch();
    }

}
```

Error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.mycompany.mavenproject4.App.main(App.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:873)
```

Comment: Have you put the JAR file containing the JDBC driver on the runtime classpath?

Comment: I have added the dependency in maven pom the jar appear in the dependencies. How do I add it in runtime classpath with maven netbeans? This is strange because normal java maven project works. The problem only occur with netbeans maven javafx projects. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is the project : https://github.com/herve-ch/testJavaFXJdbc
It uses jdk8 with javaFX, created with Netbeans 12
Its a clean project, i just try to add Jt400 jdbc jar and use some AS400 class, i always get Class not found.
Adding jt400 in compile scope should work in runtime scope too right?

Answer (score 0):

i changed maven archtype and it works now

Thanks